# Showing uploaded image with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, image-uploading

I'm having a huge problem showing an image uploaded in Spring Boot, problem is that the first time I upload it, the path is perfectly fine and everything is good but image not displaying, when i restart the server the image shows.

I think it's because when starting the project it compiles into a .jar without the image, so before restarting the project the image don't really exists.

I dont know how to fix this, not sure if possible.

The image is saved under static/img

[image]

Thank you alot

Comment: Where are you storing this image?

Comment: I'm storing it under static/img/

Comment: how your trying show the image, i mean are you using link or resource?

Comment: <img src="...">. From thyemleaf (the first time it doesnt work but the second time it does so I dont think its due img tag syntax)

Comment: i face the same problem and i the first solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464942/spring-boot-load-image-after-upload) works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i could slove this error, it seems that it was due IntellIj and a maven dependencies i wasn't using:

I did this:
**In intell IJ**

1) Help->Find Action... and type "Registry", in the dialog search for "automake" and enable the entry "compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running", close dialog
2) enable background compilation in Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler "Make project automatically"
3) Open Spring Boot run config, you should get warning message if everything is configured correctly
4) Run your app, change your classes and static content on-the-fly

I also added this maven dependencies
   org.springframework.boot
   spring-boot-devtools

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that you might be storing the image in webapps. If so:

`Do not use the src/main/webapp directory if your application will be packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it will only work with war packaging and it will be silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.`

I am assuming when you put this on your server it is a war file so the above does not matter.

[Spring-Boot Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html)

Comment: Nope, i might have explained wrong (English not my mothertoungue) gonna try again: I im running spring boot with its embebed tomcat, and i'm saving images under static/img folder