# How to display file outside root directory java spring project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, path

I have database where store path to images and some title,id,description. When I store pictures in path resources/static/img/pic.png that's work fine, but when I add new query to database with picture it's save in folder, but can't display, so I need to restart application for see them.

I try create folder in folder with src(screenshot)[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDBPs.png), also I add resource handler:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noStore());
        registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:anination07/uploads/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noStore());
    }
```

also in security config this:

```
.requestMatchers("/img/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/storage/**","/users_pic/**","/posts_pic/**","/uploads/**").permitAll()
```

in html I get this, one located in static path displays, but in uploads no:
.
When I add a new entry to the database, the java code adds an image to the correct folder, but it cannot display it

Answer (score 0):

ok, I solve it, searching similar problem [here solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464942/spring-boot-load-image-after-upload). Maybe someone needs it. Put a folder near "java" and "resources" folders and add this handler to config:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/upload/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:///" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/upload/");
```

Comment: Nice you solved this, but perhaps this is not the best way to store images. But of course this depends on your environment.